# VB Compile Error: list separator or ) with CStr

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with one line in code in VB, which gives me error

```
Vb Compile Error expected: list separator or )
```

The line is:

```
Range("C" & CStr(k) ":F" & CStr(k)).Select
```

where k is counter - counts number of the sheets

seems quite basic, but I think the problem is putting ":F" after CStr(k) (but I need to select 3 cells)

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks quite basic, surely you meant to put & in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an &

```
Range("C" & CStr(k) & ":F" & CStr(k)).Select
```